# Adding a css class to an input if it has an error using devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, simple-form

I'm at a point in my app where if the users encounters an error in the form I'd like to change the appearance of a an input. From what I see, devise doesn't add any classes to the input per se if this is the case. Is there any built-in way to achieve this without doing it manually by checking for errors: `resource.errors[:username].any?`

```
<%= f.input :username, wrapper: false, input_html: { class: "#{'error' if resource.errors[:username].any? }" } %>
```

**Note:** I pass in `wrapper: false`, which eliminates the addition of `fields_with_errors` class appended to the wrapper.

Comment: @ryanwebjackson It shouldn't. This is standard AR validation handled by Simple Form.